# how send image via httpurlconnection

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

```java
public void sendFile(File[] files) {
          httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
          httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
          httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
          httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
          httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
          httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
          httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
          httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=*****");
          BufferedOutputStream dos = new BufferedOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());

          dos.write("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=*****\r\n".getBytes());
          dos.write("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n".getBytes());
          for (File file : files) {
            if(file.length() <= 0)
              continue;

            BufferedInputStream fileInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file.getAbsoluteFile()));

            String what_is_here = String.format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"files\"; filename=\"%s\"\r\n",
                    file.getAbsoluteFile());
            dos.write("--*****--\r\n".getBytes());
            dos.write(what_is_here.getBytes());
            dos.write("\r\n".getBytes());
            dos.flush();
            byte[] b = new byte[(int) file.length()];

            for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
              b[i] = (byte) fileInput.read();
            }

            dos.write(b);
            dos.write("\r\n".getBytes());
            dos.flush();
            fileInput.close();
          }
          dos.write("--*****--\r\n".getBytes());
          dos.flush();
          dos.close();
          Log.wtf("STATUS", httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() + "");
}
```

My question is about what is wrong with this code? I am trying to send image from my tablet (android) to my local server (spring) and It is not working spring server does not see files which I am sending.

```java
@PostMapping("/file")
  public void handleFileUpload(@RequestParam MultipartFile[] files) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("FILES: " + files.length);
  }
```

I am using this method to catch files but sysout prints length equals 0;

When I do the call to this method via postman it works fine. So that why I am thinking there is something wrong with android app. Please give me some suggestions cause I was trying many

Comment: Did you try to use ip address  instead of using `localhost`. example `URL url = new URL("192.168.44.2");`

Comment: Have you considered using Retrofit instead? You won't have to deal with writing all of this code

Comment: @TaQuangTu I did not use 'localhost' just IP I made once that mistake. Zun I would prefere only to use httpurlconnection